# Upper bound on the Gaussian Q-function proof

Tags: integration

I have found the following proof of an upper bound on the Gaussian Q-function. In the proof $\phi(\cdot)$ is the standard normal PDF. The substitution made is $v = \frac{u^2}{2}$.

$$
Q(x) = \int_x^\infty\phi(u)du < \int_x^\infty\frac{u}{x}\phi(u)du = \int_{\frac{x^2}{2}}^\infty\frac{e^{-v}}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}dv = \frac{\phi(x)}{x}
$$

I am not able to understand the inequality between the two integrals in the above proof. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are integrating from $x$ to $\infty$ $\frac u x >1$ and $\frac u x \phi (u)>\phi (u)$. Now integrate.